# How do I end a service when the Android application closes?

Tags: android, android-service

I understand that when you call an `Intent` to start a service, the service continues until it  is explicitly ended.

I would like the service to persist multiple activities. How do I end it when all activities of the application is destroyed?

Or does it get destroyed automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main `Activity`, override `onDestroy` and call `stopService`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(<Context>, "Stopping service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(<MainActivity>.this, <YourService>.class);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Would the main `Activity` be destroyed if it launches another activity (part of the same app) via an `Intent`?

Comment: No. If you observe the `Activity` lifecycle, an activity is created and destroyed once. If you call `Activity` B from `Activity` A, the calling `Activity` is paused.

Comment: Why, then, does `onCreate()` get called again when I return from `Activity` B to `Activity` A?

Comment: @Aashish The `Activity` will stay on `onPause()` for as long as it is visible (i.e. if `Activity` B is a themed as a `Dialog` for example), otherwise it will go to `onStop()` as it can be seen from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states)

Comment: @Emmanuel, Thanks fro correcting me. The statement for `onDestroy` holds true.

Comment: @Emmanuel Thanks, I have seen that page too before coming here, hence my question. I know how to stop a service. I just don't know how to make it stop when the last app activity is destroyed. If I were to follow @Aashish's solution, the service would terminate when my app launches another activity via an `Intent`. The new activity relies on this service.

Comment: @mushroom, my assumption is that, the last activity to be destroyed will be launcher activity. `Android` maintains a stack of activities. Did you try my solution, BTW?

Comment: @Aashish Yes, I did. The service got destroyed when my Main activity launched another activity.

Comment: @Aashish what prevents you from using the method provided by this answer in the `onDestroy()` of your last `Activity`?

Comment: @mushroom, can you try ` isFinishing` instead of `onDestroy`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()

Comment: @Emmanuel `isFinishing()` also gets called when transitioning to another Activity within the app.

Comment: It wasn't me who suggested that answer.

Comment: @Aashish I may not have explained the situation as clear as it should be. So as an extension to this question, here's what I believe the underlying problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615566/android-application-lifecycle.