# Android Application Lifecycle and back button

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I've read the Android Docs on the lifecycle of an activity. However, I am curious as to how different activities within an application behaves.

From some tests that I've done, transitioning from Activity A to Activity B within the same application via an intent pauses Activity A via `onPause()` and creates Activity B via `onCreate()`.

The strange part is when Activity B transitions back to Activity A.

If the hardware back key is pressed, `onPause()` is fired for Activity B and `onResume()` is fired for Activity A. This is what I would expect.

However, if the back button on the `ActionBar` is pressed, `onDestroy()` is fired for Activity A followed by `onCreate()` and `onResume()`.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "back button" on the `ActionBar` is called the "Up Button". This is the expected behaviour of the Up Button, if you take a look of the implementation of the code which performs the "up", you see that Activity A is recreated.

```
Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
parentActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
finish();
```

You can define what the "Up" button should do, **however, I suggest to stick to the default behaviour**.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Your Code Here.
            break;
    }
}
```

**Why?**

The *Up* Button (in contrast to the back button) should navigate one level higher in the application hierarchy, **always.** The back button should go *back*, even if it will leave the current application. 
You can't just call finish on the current `Activity`, because the parent `Activity` could already be garbage collected and don't exist anymore.

I heavily suggest to read the official [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html), especially the part about [Up vs Back](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back).

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer here. Is there any way to make the "Up Button" perform like the "Back Button" so that the parent Activity does not have to be recreated.

Comment: Yes, you can override this behaviour.

Comment: Are there any reasons to "stick to the default behaviour"? The use-case for this is so that the previous activity (a ListView) will not have to be recreated as scroll position would be lost.

Comment: Nice answer! Can you perhaps explain why the default behavior is supposed to be better than just `finish`ing the current `Activity`? (Assuming the current `Activity` was started by the parent `Activity`).

Comment: @mushroom Scroll positions can be saved using onSaveInstanceState :)

Comment: @mushroom And restore in onRestoreInstanceState ;)

Comment: @NiekHaarman See my edit, why you can't just call `finish();`.

Comment: "You can't just call finish on the current Activity, because the parent Activity could already be garbage collected and don't exist anymore." How, then, should I ensure that users pressing the hardware back button would go one level up?

Comment: The back button doesn't go a level up, it goes back. And you basically can't, but Android will take care of this.